# Past and present event from mysql database compare today by using php

Tags: php, mysql, date

i want to get past and future events from database and by using php-mysql query, and  i had try with this query

```
select * from table name where date >date();
```

but i got the past events in future section. and i saved date in varchar data type.
please help me
Thank You

Comment: First of all: do **not** store date in varchar! You don't want to compare apples and oranges

Comment: You need to save the date in any of mysql's date types.

Answer (score 0):

Use NOW() MySQL function to get current timestamp and STR_TO_DATE function to convert string date to date format

```
select * from table_name where STR_TO_DATE(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') > now();
```

But you really should consider to alter your table to TIMESTAMP data type

Comment: thanks for ur reply ,  thats not possible because date come from client's entry